# Lost a Control on a WinForm

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, controls

I've been recursively refining a UI with visual Studio 2008, and I seem to have lost a control underneath the myriad layers of other controls. the project *is* checked into our version control software (I check in after I make a substantial enough change - for instance moving something around on or adding to the UI, or adding a method).

The refining of the UI has come directly from the boss, and he loves to move things around as we're discussing any changes that need to be made - which isn't that bad, I suppose. I check in before he starts faffing, and write down everything he does (in case we need to re-create it), then if nothing major has changed check the UI out again.

I suppose that I should mention that I'm using .Net 3.5 (because we can't upgrade to VS2010, yet) and C#, with a few custom controls (but most of them are the built-in .NET ones).

Somewhere down the line, I've lost a text box control. It's still listed in the Form properties window, and I can still select it from there. But when I look over at the form, there doesn't seem to be anything highlighted.

I've moved most of the controls around (where possible, as some of them are docked to sides of the form, or each other. Bad UI design, I know. But that's how the boss wanted it) and re-ordered them (send to back/front), and can get all the way back down to the background of the form (in most places). But I still can't find it.

At this point, I'm inclined to delete/remove the control from the form and start again with it rather than find it and move it into the new position. But, since I can't seem to find it, I'm not sure if I can.

Is it possible to delete the control in some way other than selecting it and hitting the delete key? I'd rather not have to jump back to an older version of the UI as I've made that many small changes, recently (and checked in after each one) and I have no idea when this text box got lost.

**EDIT:**

In case it's useful, here are some of the properties of the text box control:

- Size: 356, 0
- Location: 1, 1
- Multiline: True
- Text:
- Dock: Fill

I've added text to the text property, and moved everything again and still can't find it. I've also been messing around with the Dock property in an effort to move it around the form to make it easier to find.

Also, most of the UI uses group boxes and panels, as I've found it easier to hide and disable/show and enable groups of controls as and when needed that way.

**EDIT 2:**

The text boxes properties are now (based on some helpful suggestions in the answers):

- Size: 356, 150
- Location: 150, 150
- Dock: None
- Multiline: True
- Text: "Where are you?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be few issue. Try these.

1. If u using team server along studio then u can right click the pending changes and see with older version where u see the changes done by previous vs current so u know want went wrong.
2. The control property visibility set to true. I.e: textbox1.visibility= true;
3. If the control is docked to fill then it wraps the other control under it. So try playin with the control properties.

Comment: We're not using Team Server, there're only two of us developers at the minute and we're creating, relatively, small projects. Visibility is set to true. I've changed the Dock property to None (following @Daniel Hilgarth's 2nd suggestion)

Comment: Ok mate, u gonna laugh at this.. Anyway try to place a new control on the form which should be visible. Now copy the control name ex: textbox2, and go to code view and search the no of places it's been used such as in initilize components() etc.. And now back to ur old control name and check weather it's also exists the same places as new one. Should work.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. In that, by following the steps you mentioned then removing all references to the original (now lost) textbox control within my FormName.designer, it seems to have been deleted from the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, it has a height of 0 (Size: 356, **0**). Change that to something meaningful and you will start seeing the control again.

Comment: Except that every time I change the height to any positive integer other than 0, the value snaps back to 0 automatically. great suggestion, though

Comment: @JamieTaylor: Try to change the control to not docked and change the height afterwards. Maybe the panel it is docked in also has a height of 0?

Comment: Dock is now set to "None", Location is "150, 150" and Size is "356, 150" and it's still not showing up (even as selected). Great suggestions, though. I didn't think of the Docking issue